# Design an ER diagram

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram, entities

We now want to design an appropriate schema for our BiblioVT system. The DBLP
dataset contains information about approximately 1.4 million publications in the
computer science literature. Here is a complete description of what your E/R diagram
should model.
• Each publication has a unique string called the dblp_key that identifies it. It also has a title, a year of publication, and one or more authors.

• Some types of publications do not have authors: they have editors (see below).

• The order in which authors appear in a publication is important and must be
recorded. In each publication, each author appears at most once. The rank of a author is unique within the publication. Within a publication, ranks must start at 0 and be consecutive. For some publications, the authors have not been recorded.

• A publication may also have a URL and a Digital Object Identifier (DOI).

• Each publication can cite one or more publications (these are the list of references that appear at the end of a typical publication). In addition, each publication can be associated with one or more topics. Topics are themselves arranged hierarchically, e.g., see the Computing Classification System. A topic can be a sub-topic of more than one "parent" topic and itself have one or more specialized topics as "children".
• Each publication belongs to one of the following categories:

o article: This type corresponds to a journal article. The publication will have an associated journal name, a volume and a number specifying the issue
of the journal, page numbers, and a publisher of the journal.

o book: As the name indicates, this type of publication is a book. It also has a
publisher, series and an ISBN number. Book has two types “Author book”
and “Editor book”. Author book is a regular book with one or more
authors. The contents of an “Editor book” is gathered by one or more
editors.

o incollection: This type indicates a publication contained within a collection as chapter. Each incollection will have its own page numbers and authors.
A chapter in a collection has a cross reference to the collections it was
published in.

o inproceedings: This type indicates a paper published in the proceedings of a scientific conference. It is very similar to a publication of type
"incollection". A publication of type "inproceedings" has a cross reference
to the proceedings it was published in.
o collections: An example of a collection is a book that contains different
chapters written by different authors (note that every book is not
necessarily a collection). Each chapter in a collection will have the type
incollection. The entire collection itself is considered a separate
publication and has its own title, a list of editors, and a publisher. It is not possible for a person to be an author of a collection, i.e., collections only have editors. Within a single collection, an editor appears at most once. Within a single collection, ranks of editors are also unique and
consecutively numbered starting at 0.

o proceedings: The conference “proceedings” is itself a separate publication
with its own title, editors, and publisher. Editors and their ranks for a
"proceeding" have the same function and constraints as for a "collection".

o mastersthesis: This publication is a Master's thesis, with a specific author, and publisher and year. Publisher has the information about department
and/or university.

o phdthesis: This publication is a PhD thesis, with a specific author, publisher and year. Publisher has the information about the department and/or
university.

o www: This type of "publication" is just a pointer to a web page, possibly
with a title and one or more authors. It must have a URL.

Comment: Try to build some ERD and then post here. We will give suggestions on that.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply , But the thing is , I find it really difficult to create any relation between any of the two entities. The question will bring everyone to a conclusion that it is an enhanced entity relationship model problem but it actually is an ER problem .

Comment: I agree, try to start with simplest entities and make their attributes and relations. Then add remaining entities one by one or feature wise.

Comment: Should I create a DBLP_KEY for every entity or create an {Entity : Publication } with the five general attributes(including the dblp_key)  and generalize it with all of the categories of publication ?

Comment: email me at `ping@naveedramzan.com`

Comment: Subtypes in classic ER can be handled as weak entity sets without weak keys. However, disjoint subtype constraints aren't supported by classic ER. If required, I would just annotate the ER model/diagram and add additional columns and constraints in the physical model/implementation.